# How to add an object to an array only if certain condition is true using typescript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i have an array like below,

```
const arr: Column<Data>[] = [
    {
        Header: 'Header1',
        id: 'some_id1',
        Cell: ({value}) => 
            value ? (
                <div>hello</div>
            ) : null,
    } as ColumnWithId<Data>,
    ......
    ......
    ......
    ......
    //many other objects present
]
```

Now if the condition say isCheck true then it should add another object so the array would like below,

```
const arr: Column<Data>[] = [
    {
        Header: 'Header1',
        id: 'some_id1',
        Cell: ({value}) => 
            value ? (
                <div>hello</div>
            ) : null,
    } as ColumnWithId<Data>,
    {
        Header: 'Header2',
        id: 'some_id2',
        Cell: ({value}) => 
            value ? (
                <div>hello</div>
            ) : null,
     } as ColumnWithId<Data>,
        
    ......
    ......
    ......
    ......
    //many other objects present
]
```

below is the code,

```
const setColumns = ({isCheck} : {isCheck: boolean;}) => {
    const columns: Column<Data>[] = [
        {
             Header: 'Header1',
             id: 'some_id1',
             Cell: ({value}) => 
                 value ? (
                     <div>hello</div>
                 ) : null,
        } as ColumnWithId<Data>,
        ......
        ......
        ......
        ......
        //many other objects present
    ];
    return columns;
};


const ParentComponent: React.FC<> = () => {
    const columns = React.useMemo(() => 
        setColumns({ isCheck }),
        [isCheck]
    );
    
    return (
        //some jsx
    );
}
```

How can i add another object to array if this isCheck is true. i have tried something like below.

```
const setColumns = ({isCheck} : {isCheck: boolean;}) => {
    const columns: Column<Data>[] = isCheck ? [
        {
             Header: 'Header1',
             id: 'some_id1',
             Cell: ({value}) => 
                 value ? (
                     <div>hello</div>
                 ) : null,
        } as ColumnWithId<Data>,
        {
            Header: 'Header2',
            id: 'some_id2',
            Cell: ({value}) => 
                value ? (
                    <div>hello</div>
                ) : null,
        } as ColumnWithId<Data>,
           
        ......
        ......
        ......
        ......
        //many other objects present
    ] : [
        {
            Header: 'Header1',
            id: 'some_id1',
            Cell: ({value}) => 
                value ? (
                    <div>hello</div>
                ) : null,
        } as ColumnWithId<Data>,
        .....
        .....
        .....
        .....
        //many other objects present
    ];
        
    return columns;
};
```

the above works. but as you see i am copying the same array (which contains many other objects) if the condition is true and adding one object to array. usually this array has many objects and copying it in code like in above setColumns method makes the code look clumsy.

so was thinking of a better solution to this. could someone help me with this. i am new to programming. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array push to do this

```
const setColumns = ({isCheck} : {isCheck: boolean;}) => {
    // Declare the initial array with the objects that should exist either way
    const columns: Column<Data>[] =[
        {
            Header: 'Header1',
            id: 'some_id1',
            Cell: ({value}) => 
                value ? (
                    <div>hello</div>
                ) : null,
        } as ColumnWithId<Data>,
        .....
        .....
        .....
        .....
        //many other objects present
    ];

    // Conditionally add the additional element
    if(isCheck){
       columns.push({
            Header: 'Header2',
            id: 'some_id2',
            Cell: ({value}) => 
                value ? (
                    <div>hello</div>
                ) : null,
            } as ColumnWithId<Data>
       )
    }
    return columns;
};
```